# Не включать определенные ресурсы/классы в релизный apk

Tags: android

Не могу разобраться, как не включать определенные ресурсы (из папки res) и классы (java) в релизный apk.

Пробовал packagingOptions/exclude - не выкидывает.

С proguard вообще не нашёл правил для этого (хотя может просто плохо искал).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто ресурсы и классы нужные только для debug сборки кладите не в src/main а в src/debug папку.
Для более сложных вариантов сборки можете использовать [flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors). Вообще [по этой ссылке](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) всё довольно подробно расписано, разве что на английском.

Comment: Вариант с src/debug не проходит. Точнее как, для app проходит, а для либы нет. Давайте объясню. У меня есть отладочные классы/ресурсы (они что-то показывают, контролируют...) Соответственно я их использую в приложении только для debug сборки. Но это классы я использую в разных проектах, соответственно вынес их в либу (модуль) и подключаю к разным проектам через `project(':xxx').projectDir = new File('xxxx')`. И только проблема, что при сборке либ берётся release вариант. Т.е. класть его в debug/release я не вижу смысла, соотвественно остаются классы в main либы. Всё работает.

Comment: Но эти классы/ресурсы есть в обоих сборках, а мне надо только в debug. Понимаете? Как мне помогут flavor-ы я не совсем понимаю.

Comment: Ну в варианте с либой тогда сделайте отдельную либу в которой будут только отладочные ресурсы и классы и подключайте её только для отладочной сборки приложения

Comment: Кстати да. Почему-то самый простой вариант и не пришел на ум.

Comment: Единственный момент (как я понял из комментариев http://stackoverflow.com/a/22442719/238089) - это работает с андроид либами, а с простыми java либами нет. Но мне это не важно, потому что у меня как раз андроид либа.

Comment: у обычных жава либ просто помойму по умолчанию нет разных вариантов сборки, если же добавить вараинты debug и release, то будет то же самое)